# VS2012: show onle _one_ file in code review mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs-code-review

I'm conducting a code review in VS2012RC using built in tool (TFS?)

There have been substantial refactoring done to the file, so diff is meaningless. I would like to see only new file (i.e. without diffs). Is there a way to configure code review view to see only one file?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you seek is implemented in [alternative code review tool](http://www.devart.com/review-assistant/) that is called Review Assistant.
It's an add-in for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, and works with TFS.